# How to handle negative integer in ANTLR4 grammar targetting C++

Tags: regex, antlr4

I am making a calculator with ANTLR4 targetting C++
and I am trying to handle the integer (...-1,0,1,....) with the g4 code below.

```
INT :'-'? [0-9]+ ;
```

this is based on regex

```
[-]?[0-9]+
```

But this accept -0 case
How can I handle modify code to get rid of this negative zero case?

Comment: Typically this is a parser rule "unary negation" with the proper precedence according to the the language you're modeling.  Typically  a high precedence.  [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence]

Answer (score 0):

Is there another (valid) interpretation of ”-0”?

If negative 0 is the only way to understand “-0”, but you want it to be considered invalid, then leave your rule as-is, and do that check in your own code during semantic validation.  You’ll be able to give a good specific error message, whereas, if you exclude it from the Lexer rule, you’re going to get an error in the Tokenization phase, or have your input tokenized in a way the generates a rather obscure syntax error directly from ANTLR.

Generally, consider your Lexer/Parser goal to be to interpret your input in “the only reasonable way to understand that input” (even it if might be invalid usage in your language).  It seems to be a common temptation to encode “all the rules possible” into the grammar. This won’t necessarily serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider not including negative in your lexical rules.
I think you'll find that by treating negation as a prefix operation (or a simple operation) it will simplify your parser later on.
For example, consider how you might handle an expression like:

```
2 + 1 - -1
```

Your might find your lexer attempts to grab the first minus as the start of an INT.

So. I'd be tempted to do something like:

```
expression : POS_INT #literal_expr
           | MINUS expression #negate_expr
           | expression addOp expression #add_expr
           ;

addOp : PLUS | MINUS;
POS_INT : [0-9]+;
MINUS : '-';
PLUS : '+';
```